# SharkBite fitting and galvanize pipe

Tags: plumbing

Can a SharkBite fitting be connected to galvanized pipe? I have a broken galvanized water pipe on the outside of the house. I want to connect a PEX pipe with SharkBite to the place where the galvanized pipe broke.

Comment: Why cant you use a union or a compression fitting with the oldschool rubber seal.Cut the threads off the galvanized pipe first and sand and clean the mating surfaces for the seal.Then run pex straight out of a coupling into whatever.Youd nolonger need the sharkbite.Anybody using galvanized pipe for burial pipe is asking for trouble anyway and should replace it according to egress or local codes. Galvanized pipe is only good for 10 years tops.Especially if used for burial.

Comment: Galvanized pipe is most definitely good for more than just 10 years. We have galvanized in and above ground on our property for at least 100+ years. Authoritive sources suggest 40-100 years. We are using a hose clamp/ steel braided hydraulic hose to pipe fitting for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The actual SharkBite push to connect fittings are not designed to press onto galvanized pipe.

For mating your PEX to galvanized, SharkBite makes a threaded to press fit transition adapter.
You will need to square cut the end of your galvanized pipe and then rethread it.

Comment: Just so folks know treading galvanized is non trivial exercise on site. for DIYer it means buying or renting an expensive die tool.  Then hope you can cut it off straight with a hack saw and hope that there is enough clearance for the die and the handle.

Comment: Although it may not be 100% kosher you can try something like this https://www.grainger.com/product/MUELLER-Coupling-21TF15?functionCode=P2IDP2PCP with a treaded nipple in the other end if threading is not an option.